SQL инъекция к сайту
Проводится поиск уязвимости на сайте посредством ввода инъекции в адресную строку браузера путем вывода пароля пользователя из базы данных.
Взята таблица news, в которой находится  4 столбца, и выводится новость на страницу посредством id. Таблица users состоит из 7 столбцов.
 SELECT * FROM news WHERE news.news_id= 12 UNION SELECT user_id, user_name, user_password, user_date FROM users
ВВОД когда осуществляется инъекция:
http://name.ru/news/12+UNION+SELECT+user_id,user_name,user_password,user_date+FROM+users 
Соответственно Инъекция не проходит, так как запятые в запросе не проходят на сервер. Если бы количество столбцов совпадало в таблицах news и users, инъекция бы прошла путем
http://name.ru/news/12+UNION+SELECT+user_password+FROM+users
Вопрос, есть ли способ написать другую инъекцию не используя "," и "=" и "'", так чтобы она прошла, и не выдавало ошибки, что не совпадает количество столбцов в таблицах.

«запятые в запросе не проходят на сервер» — почему?

заблокированы при обработки внутренних php запросов и конвертации их на сервер

Ну значит как минимум можно изучить, как именно заблокированы, и попробовать найти методы обхода этих блокировок, ну там например первое что в голову приходит — %2C и %252C
